# Chrome web driver: Curl error thrown for http DELETE to /session/XXX

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver, facebook-php-webdriver

I using Chromedriver together with Facebook PHP webdriver. I often encounter with a session problems.

```
Curl error thrown for http DELETE to /session/XXXX
```

How resolve this problem? Why does it happen?

Full error code:

```
Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received {"exception":"[object] (Facebook\\WebDriver\\Exception\\WebDriverCurlException(code: 0): Curl error thrown for http DELETE to /session/da095582d77523239753bb0e30adaa6d

Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received at /var/www/html/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:286)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php(535): Facebook\\WebDriver\\Remote\\HttpCommandExecutor->execute(Object(Facebook\\WebDriver\\Remote\\WebDriverCommand))
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php(277): Facebook\\WebDriver\\Remote\\RemoteWebDriver->execute('quit')
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase time:

```
$connection_timeout_in_ms = 6000;   // Timeout for the connect phase to remote Selenium WebDriver server in ms
$request_timeout_in_ms = 90000;     // Set the maximum time of a request to remote Selenium WebDriver server in ms        

$chromeDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create(
        $url['url'],
        $capabilities,
        $connection_timeout_in_ms,
        $request_timeout_in_ms
);
```

Comment: What if it still timesout after increasing the time? What is the real solution?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the new latest version of selenium.